# Log into website then go to url that redirects

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have these two php scripts and what I want to is combine them, but I keep getting errors. The first script logs into the website then goes to the member only page and displays the contents. The second script does a good job at following redirects.

What I want to do is combine the scripts so that it logins in sucessfully and then goes to this members only page where it redirects to another members only page.

Login script:

```
   $username = 'myuser';
    $password = 'mypass';
    $loginUrl = 'http://www.example.com/login/';

    //init curl
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the URL to work with
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

    // ENABLE HTTP POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //Set the post parameters
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

    //Handle cookies for the login
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

    //Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
    //not to print out the results of its query.
    //Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
    //from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //execute the request (the login)
    $store = curl_exec($ch);

    //the login is now done and you can continue to get the
    //protected content.

    //set the URL to the protected file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/protected/download.zip');

    //execute the request
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $content;
```

2nd script that follows redirects

```
  $res = array();
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page 
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // do not return headers 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects 
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i 
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect 
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response 
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects 
); 
$ch      = curl_init("http://page.com/redirector.php"); 
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
$content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
$err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
curl_close( $ch ); 

$res['content'] = $content;     
$res['url'] = $header['url'];
echo $res['content'];
```

Comment: we can't help much if you don't let us know what error you're getting

Comment: I get 404 not found errors on the website and such, but thats only because I'm not good with php, so I don't really know how to combine them the right way so I'm hoping someone here can

Comment: if you're getting a 404, that would mean that the web page is not found. It won't be anything on the script itself. Make sure the site you're trying to visit actually exists, and check that you don't have any typos in the url in the php script.

Comment: Yes the page does exist. It's my faulty coding.